# Create an object literal with ComputedPropertyName in arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, computed-properties

How to convert this:

```js
const array = [10, 0, 90, 80, 50, 0, 60];
let id = 1;

const studentScores = array.map(function(score, index){
  return { [index]: score, student_id: id } 
});

console.log(studentScores)
```

Into fat arrow syntax:

```
const studentScores = array.map((score, index) => { [index]: score, student_id: id } );
```

My try throws an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to parenthesize the object literal to convince the parser that it *is* an object literal:

```
const studentScores = array.map((score, index) => ({ [index]: score, student_id: id }) );
```

By wrapping it in parentheses, the parser is forced to interpret it as an *expression* and not a *statement block*. The `{` character has that ambiguity, and when it's the first thing in a statement the parser always assumes "statement block" is what it's seeing.

Answer (score 2):

To *implicitly* return an object with arrow function, wrapp it with parentheses:

```
const studentScores = array.map((score, index) => ({ [index]: score, student_id: id }) );
```

Comment: Implicitly? Don't you mean explicitly?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, implicitly. It's explicitly when you put a return. Here, I don't write `return` keywork so it's implicit

Comment: Oh, I never hear that described as an "implicit" return... Interesting.